# Testes Unitários .net MVC - Problema com HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testes-de-unidade

Boa tarde,

Tenho a seguinte aplicação como solution:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

        UtilizadorDbo utilizadorDbo = new UtilizadorDbo();
        ViewBag.userLogon = utilizadorDbo.getUtilizador(util.getClientUser(username)).nome;

        ViewBag.dataPT = util.getDatetimePT();

        return View();
    }
```

Enquanto que no teste unitario tenho o seguinte:

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        // Arrange
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        // Act
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }

}
```

Mas sempre que tento correr o teste, este falha indicando System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Apontando para a linha referente HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;

Li que deveria fazer um Mock do Context, mas não sei como fazer, alguém me consegue ajudar?

Cumprimentos

Comment: Isso é .NET Core?

Comment: Estou a usar .NET MVC

Comment: Não existe .NET MVC. O que eu quis perguntar é qual framework está usando: .NET Framework, .NET Core ou .NET 5...

Comment: Usando .NET Framework

Comment: seta o `HttpContext.Current` no teste, assim: `HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(... passe os parametros....)`

Comment: Conseguiu evolouir aí?